# How can I properly check if a collections.abc class is empty?

Tags: python

When starting out in Python we're all told that this is how you check if a sequence (list, tuple, set, dict, etc.) is empty:

```py
if not cookies:
    print("The cookie monster needs his cookies")
```

and *not* like this:

```py
if not len(cookies):
    print("This is bad")
if cookies == []:
    print("This is just wrong")
```

Once we learn some more Python we might learn that it's good to write code that caters to interfaces from [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) instead of assuming the built-in collections like `list`, `dict`, `set`, `tuple`, etc. Now we might think it's proper to write a function like this one:

```py
def eat(cookies: Sequence[Cookie]):
    if not cookies:
        raise ValueError("The cookie monster needs his cookies")
    print("Yum yum")
```

or even something like this, which is actually wrong because generators for example always give `bool(gen) == True`:

```py
def eat(cookies: Iterable[Cookie]):
    if not cookies:
        raise ValueError("The cookie monster needs his cookies")
    print("Yum yum")

cookies = (ChocoChipCookie(), OatmealCookie(), PeanutButterCookie(), SugarCookie())

eat(c for c in cookies if isinstance(c, RasinCookie)) # Wrongly prints "Yum yum"
eat([c for c in cookies if isinstance(c, RasinCookie)]) # Correctly raises ValueError
```

I'd always assumed that some interface in [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) defined `__bool__` or even inferred it from `__len__` but I noticed today that bool is not even mentioned in `collections.abc`'s documentation, not even for the most complete ones like `Sequence` even though it could easily be provided by `Sized` which defines `__len__`.

The absence of `__bool__` makes even the first implementation of `eat()` wrong, since there's no guarantee that a subclass of `Sequence` implements `__bool__` and has it behave like we'd expect.

What's the correct way to check emptiness of all the different collections in `collections.abc`, if any, and why don't they (at least some of them) define `__bool__`?

Comment: Sequences, like other Collections, are Sized, so an empty sequence _is_ [false-y](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). It's the more general Iterable that isn't Sized, you can't determine an iterator's length without consuming it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of checking for "emptiness" simply does not make sense for many of the classes defined in `collections.abc`. In particular, the example you give in the question, the `Iterable` class, can only be checked for emptiness when an actual attempt to consume an item from it is made--if it turns out to be empty, great, but if it is not, then oops, too bad, the mere attempt to check for emptiness will have irreversibly altered the state of the iterable/iterator/generator. This is why the `__bool__` method is implemented only in classes where it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with some custom collections and looking at some more documentation, I realised that [the `bool()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) covers this:

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns `False` or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object.